# Redux thunk dispatch does not work for multiple api calls

Tags: react-native, redux, react-redux

My Redux thunk dispatch was working until i made a single API call but stopped working after using combineReducers for multiple api calls.

This is my component code :

```
const mapStateToProps = state => ({
    loading: state.loading,
    data: state.data,
    error: state.error,
    networkError: state.networkError
})

const mapDispatchToProps = {
    login
}
```

These are my Actions :

```
export const GET_LOGIN_LOADING = "GET_LOGIN_LOADING"
export const GET_LOGIN_SUCCESS = "GET_LOGIN_SUCCESS"
export const GET_LOGIN_ERROR = "GET_LOGIN_ERROR"

export const GET_REGISTER_LOADING = "GET_REGISTER_LOADING"
export const GET_REGISTER_SUCCESS = "GET_REGISTER_SUCCESS"
export const GET_REGISTER_ERROR = "GET_REGISTER_ERROR"
```

This is my reducer for login and register actions :

```
import * as Actions from './Actions'

const loginState = {
    loginLoading: false,
    loginData: [],
    loginError: '',
}

const registerState = {
    registerLoading: false,
    registerData: [],
    registerError: '',
}

export const loginReducer = (state = { loginState }, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case Actions.GET_LOGIN_LOADING:
            return {
                ...state,
                loginLoading: action.payload
            }

        case Actions.GET_LOGIN_SUCCESS:
            return {
                ...state,
                loginData: action.payload,
                loginLoading: false,
            }

        case Actions.GET_LOGIN_ERROR:
            return {
                ...state,
                loginError: action.payload,
                loginLoading: false,
            }

        default: return loginState
    }
}

export const registerReducer = (state = { registerState }, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case Actions.GET_REGISTER_LOADING:
            return {
                ...state,
                registerLoading: action.payload
            }

        case Actions.GET_REGISTER_SUCCESS:
            return {
                ...state,
                registerData: action.payload,
                registerLoading: false,
            }

        case Actions.GET_REGISTER_ERROR:
            return {
                ...state,
                registerError: action.payload,
                registerLoading: false,
            }

        default: return registerState
    }
}
```

My Redux Store Code :

```
import { createStore, applyMiddleware, combineReducers } from 'redux'
import thunk from 'redux-thunk'
import{ loginReducer, registerReducer } from '../redux/Reducer'

const reducer = combineReducers({loginReducer, registerReducer})

export default createStore(reducer, applyMiddleware(thunk))
```

Finally my thunk code used for making API calls :

```
export const login = (countryCode, phone, password) => {
    const userName = {
        countryCode,
        phone
    }
    return dispatch => {
        dispatch(getLoginLoading(true))
        service.post('login', {
            userName,
            password
        })
            .then(response => {
                console.log(response.data)
                dispatch(getLoginSuccess(response.data))
            })
            .catch(error => {
                console.log(error)
                dispatch(getLoginError(error.response.data))
            })
    }
}

export const register = (name, countryCode, phone) => {
    return dispatch => {
        dispatch(getRegisterLoading(true))
        service.post('register', {
            name,
            countryCode,
            phone,
        })
            .then(response => {
                console.log(response.data)
                dispatch(getRegisterSuccess(response.data))
            })
            .catch(error => {
                console.log(error.response)
                dispatch(getRegisterError(error.response))
            })
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Finally found an answer by myself. When you are use combine reducers, Redux creates a nested state object for each reducer, Hence when accessing the state you should use :

```
const reducer = combineReducers({loginReducer, registerReducer})


const mapStateToProps = state => ({
    loading: state.loginReducer.loading,
    data: state.loginReducer.data,
    error: state.loginReducer.error,
    networkError: state.loginReducer.networkError
})
```